# how to make max function in hive query to ignore _HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__

Tags: hadoop, hive, max, impala, hive-partitions

I have a view which uses max to show the latest partition (which is of format `2021-01`, `2021-02`, `2021-03`, `2021-04`). The hive table has `_HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` too.

When we run the query in Impala, max on partitions gives the correct value of `2021-04` ignoring `_HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` but the same do not work when we run the query in Hive as it returns `_HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`

Is there any way to make Hive query ignore the default partition if exists while returning max on that column?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter it:

```
select max(partition_col) from your_table where partition_col != "__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__"
```

If you do not need data in `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`, you can drop it:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table  DROP PARTITION (partition_col='__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__');
```

Transforming `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` to NULL can be a solution if with `max(partition_col)` you want to aggregate something else and do not want to excluse `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__` partition:

```
select max(case when partition_col = "__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__" then NULL else partition_col end) as max_partition_col,
       --aggregate something else including HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION
  from your_table
```